# How to drop index using mongocxx driver

Tags: c++, mongo-cxx-driver

My program is providing a configurable ttl. So I have to check ttl index every time the program starts, if the expire duration isn't correct, I have to re-index it.

I see drop index function in mongoc driver. But it seems there is no such option in mongocxx driver. Am I missing any api or is there any way to access underlying mongoc_collection_t object, so I can call mongoc driver function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to drop a single index you can use `drop_one`, either with the index name:

```
db["collection"].indexes().drop_one("department_1");
```

or with a document:

```
db["collection"].indexes().drop_one(make_document(kvp("department", 1)));
```

Be careful because it will throw if the index does not exist.

To drop all the indexes you can use `drop_all`:

```
db["collection"].indexes().drop_all();
```

You have more examples at [test/index_view.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/ac5cffb6a56de7e570ca4e697292c9a69a552f73/src/mongocxx/test/index_view.cpp#L231)